# Haskell: Converting strings into sentences

Tags: haskell

Im learning haskell and I got a problem.
The type must be:  `sentences :: [String] -> [String]`

I want to convert strings into a sentence

```
["something","","Asd dsa abc","hello world..",""]
```

to look like this: `["Something.","Asd dsa abc.","Hello world..."]`

And I want to use a higher-order function like map.
I just cant figure out how to make this.

I managed to work with a single string:

```
import Data.Char
sentences :: String -> String
sentences [] = []
sentences (a:as) = (( toUpper a):as) ++ "."
```

So I get from this:

```
sentences "sas das asd"
```

this: `"Sas das asd."`

I hope someone can help me with this problem.
Thanks for your help!

Edit: Thanks for your help now it looks like this:

```
import Data.Char
sentences :: [String] -> [String]
sentence (a:as) = ((toUpper a):as)++['.']
sentences = map sentence
```

But i dont know where to put the filter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your function coupled with map gets you half of the way, but it does not remove the empty strings from your list of strings. You can do this with filter, so in total

```
sentences ss = map sentence $ filter (/="") ss
```

Note that the core of `sentences` (plural) is simply the mapping of `sentence` (singular) over your list of strings. The filter is only there to remove the empty strings. Without this requirement, it would simply be `sentences ss = map sentence ss`.

Now you can call `sentences` with your list of strings to have each element transformed, except the empty strings that are removed by `filter`

In general, if you have a function `foo` that transforms `bar` into `baz`, you can use `map foo` to transform `[bar]` into `[baz]`

`filter`, like `map`, is a higher order function which, given a predicate function and a list, returns a list consisting of the elements for which the predicate is `True`. In this case, we give the predicate function `(/="")`, which is `True` for all strings that are not empty.

Comment: I edited my question, thanks for your help, can you help me out a bit more? Where do I need to put the filter?

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it with a list comprehension

```
import Data.Char

capFirst (l:ls) = toUpper l : ls ++ "."

sentences strings = [
                     capFirst sentence | sentence <- strings,
                     sentence /= []
                    ]

main = print $ sentences ["something","","Asd dsa abc","hello world..",""]
```